# How to add a simple phrase on a ms-word doc

Tags: c#, ms-word

im programming in C# and i need to add a simple phrase on the last page of each ms-word doc.

i have tried this

```
Word.Paragraph paragraph;
int totalPages;
Word.Range range;
range = doc.Content.Duplicate;
totalPages = range.ComputeStatistics(Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages);
range = range.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, Type.Missing, totalPages, Type.Missing);
paragraph = doc.Paragraphs.Add(range);
paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 7;
paragraph.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
paragraph.Range.Text = encrypt;
```

but this code are adding a pharse in the last but one page .

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (you may need to fix the C# syntax):

```
doc.Content.InsertParagraphAfter();
Word.Paragraph paragraph = doc.Paragraphs(doc.Paragraphs.Count());
paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 7;
paragraph.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
paragraph.Range.Text = encrypt;
```